# expected unqualified-id before 'int'? Arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino

It might be sth  stupid I missed, but its a day now I keep getting this error:(. Please help!!. This is my first library in C++ so I might have messed up the syntax.

This error appears in this line of code

```
  displayLED(int heightOfDisplay = 8, int widthOfDisplay = 32);
```

here is the code in .h file

```
#ifndef displayLED
#define displayLED
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

class displayLED
{

private:

static const int heightOfDisplay;
static const int widthOfDisplay;
int verticalArray[8];
int horizontalArray[32];
int cursorPosition=0;
const int latchPin = 8;
const int clkPin = 7;
const int REDhorizontalSO = 6;
const int GREENhorizontalSO = 11;
const int BLUEhorizontalSO = 9;
const int verticalSO = 12;



public:

displayLED(int heightOfDisplay = 8, int widthOfDisplay = 32);
displayLED();
void constructWord(String   Word = "WELCOME");
void slideIn(String colorAnimator);
void fillArrays();
void pushToRegister(int sthToWrite1[], int sthToWrite2[], int sthToWrite3[],  int sthToWrite4[], int SOpin1, int SOpin2, int SOpin3, int SOpin4);
void shiftOutMultiple(uint8_t dataPin1, uint8_t dataPin2, uint8_t dataPin3, uint8_t dataPin4, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val1, uint8_t val2, uint8_t val3, uint8_t val4)


};



#endif
```

And here is my .cpp. I have omitted other functions for brevity. I hope its clear.

```
#include "displayLED.h"


displayLED::displayLED(int heightOfDisplay, int widthOfDisplay) {
this->heightOfDisplay = heightOfDisplay;
this->widthOfDisplay = widthOfDisplay;
pinMode(latchPin , OUTPUT);
pinMode(clkPin , OUTPUT);
pinMode(REDhorizontalISO , OUTPUT);
pinMode(GREENhorizontalSO , OUTPUT);
pinMode(BLUEhorizontalSO , OUTPUT);
pinMode(vertcalISO , OUTPUT);
fillArrays();
}

displayLED::displayLED()    {
}


//this function fills all the array with zeros
void displayLED::fillArrays()   {
for(int j=0; j <= heightOfDisplay; j++) {
    verticalArray[j] = 0;
}

for(int j=0; j <= widthOfDisplay; j++)  {
    horizontalArray[j] = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Please take the time an reduce your code to a [mcve]. Remove lines one by one until you have a very small code sample that reproduces the error. Edit the post to contain that code sample only. Then paste the exact error message *verbatim*, along with how you invoke the build. You might figure out the issue yourself along the way, and if not you;ll have a solid question that will make you *waaaaaay* likelier to get the help you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `#define` guard clashes with your class name. The preprocessor will remove all mentions of `displayLed`, which yields *very* strange compile errors.

Change your guard to something like

```
#ifndef DISPLAYLED_H
#define DISPLAYLED_H
```

Alternatively, you could try using `#pragma once`. Most compilers support it nowadays.

Comment: it worked. Yaaaaaaay. Thank you